# Why is GPU picking in the three.js examples so slow on my system?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to write a visualization that displays thousands of cubes/spheres/cones and allows you to pick one with the mouse. I can't use the multiple named mesh and raycasting approach because of all the draw calls and it was suggested I investigate instancing.

I found 2 examples that do something similar [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html) and [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_instances_gpu.html) but on my system they are unusably slow - less that 1Hz. The slowdown seems to be caused by [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html#L209) line. Without it, picking is broken of course but it runs at full speed. All the other examples run normally at a steady 60Hz.

My system is a MacBook Pro with an AMD Radeon R9 M370X.

Browser is Chrome Version 71.0.3578.80. Behaves the same way with Safari 12.0.1

Can anyone suggest a workaround or different approach I can investigate?

Comment: Browser and version? Is hardware acceleration enabled in the browser settings?

Comment: Apologies for missing that information - added to original question.

Comment: are the examples slow as well, or the "something similar" ? What frame rate do you get on those particular examples?

Comment: No. The examples all run at a steady 60 fps except for the two GPU picking ones called out.

Comment: So it's safe to assume that YOUR gpu picking example is running slow, not the generic three.js one? Care to share a fiddle or something?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it more clearly.  All the three.js examples work as expected except for the 2 GPU picking ones I called out in the original question. All the examples work as expected on my iPhone (including the GPU picking ones) so there is some issue with the way it works on my Mac/GPU/OS. That's what I need help on.